# Как сделать смену позиции абсолютному элементу если он не влезает в контейнер?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать адаптивное tooltip окно.

Но возник вопрос, если tooltip 
показывается справа от элемента, как рассчитать тот момент когда он не будет влезать с правой стороны от элемента в контейнере?

И как позиционировать tooltip по вертикали что бы он оказался по середине элемента?

```js
var showingTooltip,
    elTarget;

    document.onmouseover = function(e) {
      var target = e.target;

      var tooltip = target.getAttribute('data-tooltip');
      if (!tooltip) return;

      var tooltipElem = document.createElement('div');
      tooltipElem.className = 'tooltip';
      tooltipElem.innerHTML = tooltip;
      target.appendChild(tooltipElem);

      var coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();

      var left = coords.left + target.offsetWidth;
      if (left < 0) left = 0;

      var top = coords.top - tooltipElem.offsetHeight - 5;
      if (top < 0) { 
        top = coords.top + target.offsetHeight + 5;
      }

      tooltipElem.style.left = left + 'px';
      tooltipElem.style.top = top + 'px';

      showingTooltip = tooltipElem;
      elTarget = target
    };

    document.onmouseout = function(e) {

      if (showingTooltip) {
        elTarget.removeChild(showingTooltip);
        showingTooltip = null;
      }

    };
```

```css
body {
      height: 2000px;
      }

button{

}

.wrap{
  
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

    .tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      width: 350px;

      border: 1px solid #b3c9ce;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font: italic 14px/1.3 arial, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<button data-tooltip="Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit vero corrupti veniam saepe illum officia">Короткая кнопка</button>
  <button data-tooltip="HTML<br>подсказка">Ещё кнопка</button>
  <button data-tooltip="HTML<br>подсказка">Ещё кнопка</button>
  <button data-tooltip="HTML<br>подсказка">Ещё кнопка</button>
  <button data-tooltip="HTML<br>подсказка">Ещё кнопка</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: о каком именно элементе идет речь? что нужно центрировать и где?

Comment: @Air опечатка, речь о tooltip, центровать по вертикали относительно элемента из которого был вызван tooltip

Answer (score 2):

Извините, быть может я неправильно понял вопрос, но вы ведь и так используете offset-ы. Дальше использовать обычную математику, скажем, для выравнивания по вертикали, вам нужно вычислить половину высоты кнопки:

```
coords.height / 2
```

Добавить эту высоту к отступу кнопки:

```
coords.top
```

И отнять половину высоты блока тултипа, который можно получить из

```
var coordsTooltip = tooltipElem.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Если все вместе:

```
var top = coords.top + coords.height/2 - coordsTooltip.height/2;
```

Можно еще поиграться со значением тени, чтобы выглядело более красиво.

Ваш исправленный код:

```
var showingTooltip;

    document.onmouseover = function(e) {
      var target = e.target;

      var tooltip = target.getAttribute('data-tooltip');
      if (!tooltip) return;

      var tooltipElem = document.createElement('div');
      tooltipElem.className = 'tooltip';
      tooltipElem.innerHTML = tooltip;
      document.body.appendChild(tooltipElem);

      var coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();
            var coordsTooltip = tooltipElem.getBoundingClientRect();
      var left = coords.left + target.offsetWidth;
      if (left < 0) left = 0;

      var top = coords.top + coords.height/2 - coordsTooltip.height/2;
      if (top < 0) { 
        top = coords.top + target.offsetHeight ;
      }

      tooltipElem.style.left = left + 'px';
      tooltipElem.style.top = top + 'px';

      showingTooltip = tooltipElem;
    };

    document.onmouseout = function(e) {

      if (showingTooltip) {
        document.body.removeChild(showingTooltip);
        showingTooltip = null;
      }

    };
```

Для того случая, когда элемент не будет влезать справа, можно просто рассчитать ширину контейнера (взять родителя у кнопки, ну или другим способом). Взять ширину кнопки, взять отступ у кнопки относительно контейнера. От ширины контейнера отнять отступ кнопки и его ширину - вот вам и необходимая ширина тултипа (+- тень и бордеры). После чего установить ширину тултипа и пересчитать его размеры, выровнять его по вертикали способом выше.